# Creating a asp webform to query a database with an input

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I am trying to create a c# webform that displays information from a database based on a users input. My goal would be for a user to type a number in the Store Number box and that number be used in the where cause in the select statement.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"      
CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <br />
    Store #<br />
    <input id="Text1" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    <br />

</div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Prop ID" HeaderText="Prop ID" SortExpression="Prop ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Parcel/Account" HeaderText="Parcel/Account" SortExpression="Parcel/Account" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Juris Cd" HeaderText="Juris Cd" SortExpression="Juris Cd" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address 1" HeaderText="Address 1" SortExpression="Address 1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Zip Code" HeaderText="Zip Code" SortExpression="Zip Code" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Owner" HeaderText="Owner" SortExpression="Owner" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Open Date" HeaderText="Open Date" SortExpression="Open Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Close Date" HeaderText="Close Date" SortExpression="Close Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Lease Begin" HeaderText="Lease Begin" SortExpression="Lease Begin" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Lease End" HeaderText="Lease End" SortExpression="Lease End" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Year" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Prop Type" HeaderText="Prop Type" SortExpression="Prop Type" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:masterConnectionString %>"     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Prop_Info$]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did my solution solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your sqldatasource like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConn %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT FirstName FROM Users"
    FilterExpression="FirstName='{0}'"
    runat="server">
 <FilterParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="FirstName" ControlID="txtFirstName" PropertyName="Text" />
 </FilterParameters> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" Id="txtFirstName"></asp:TextBox>
```